# Navigation Security Trimming for Headings based on child nodes

Tags: navigation, security-trimming, customization

We are using SharePoint sites to manage projects. Each project site is created from a template and security is setup for the project team with some access granted to a larger audience.

Using the Current (Structured) Navigation, we have headers called "Public Documents" and "Private Documents" with some child links below each pointing to document libraries. Each document library may have different permissions.

[image]

**Goal**: When a user does not have access to any of the child links to document libraries, security trimming prevents them from appearing. However, the header node"Private Documents" will still remain with nothing under it.

**Question**: Is there a way to have the the header node hide?

**Considerations**:

- Audience targeting: It requires managing an audience for every single user and it may vary from project to project
- Programatically Setting Links: Requires you to specify a URL to the header node.